# Having an assertion that contains one word I want it to Assert that word exists anywhere on the page with , or not

Tags: c#, selenium, appium, appium-android, appium-ios

I have a Test with an Assert in it for contains Duck.Sometimes I will see Duck,Goose. The later Fails because it sees the ,Goose. I thought Contains would fix this and I thought the * wildcard would fix this but it does not. the Test but I want my assertion to take Duck no matter what else comes after it. I am using C#. I can not find the answer correctly in Google. Here is my code:

```
        string actualvalue 
        =_driver.FindElementByXPath("//*android.widget.TextView[@text='Duck']").Text;
        Assert.IsTrue(actualvalue.Contains("Duck"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The Xpath needs to be adjusted. Your asterisk won't do the job you are looking for. In your case I believe it should look like this:

```
"//android.widget.TextView[contains(text(), 'Duck')]"
```

Comment: Is this written in Java?

Comment: @HANSTKE, as this is an xpath, it should be language-agnostic. I'm not sure what your page/DOM looks like, so I just copied and adjusted what you wrote.

Comment: Sorry C.Peck but using the xpath it does not see the Duck at all.

Comment: can you post the actual html?

Comment: I second the above.

Comment: @C.Peck yeah your xpath was good based on what was posted. This could be an iframe but who knows.